# aws boto3 grab subnet info

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-sdk

Im trying to grab a list of subnets from aws, I have a working version for VPC that I have modified:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

filters = [{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values':['*']}]
subnets = list(ec2.Subnet.filter(Filters=filters))

for subnet in subnets:
    response = client.describe_subnets(
        VpcIds=[
            vpc.id,
        ]
    )
    print(response['Subnets'])
```

I keep getting:

> subnets = list(ec2.Subnet.filters(Filters=filters)) AttributeError:
>   'function' object has no attribute 'filters'

From everything im reading and other examples this should work

Any ideas?

Comment: thanks mate worked a charm.

Comment: you are calling method id on vpc, should'nt it be subnet.id ? instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the subnets collection of `ec2` resource,

```
subnets = list(ec2.subnets.filter(Filters=filters))
```